# Cordova load resource from documents issue (WKwebview)

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage, wkwebview

We have a very simple Cordova application that downloads all the App's content to the /Documents/ folder.
Here we store html, images, css and javascripts. We recently moved to the WKWebview because the old one is deprecated. HTML is read from the documents and appended to the local index file. This all works fine. After this we try to append the script block by setting the src to 'file://.../data/Containers/Application/Documents/test.js' (the file is there).
Unfortunately this is not supported, we get the message:
Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted
We are using the latest Cordova and latest IOS platform.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?
It all works fine in the simulator but not on the iPad device.

Many thanks in advance.

Robin

Answer (score 5):

There is also a solution, which requires no significant change to the code which I found after hopeless days when no solution seemed available

There are 2 steps required:

First update your config.xml with following

```
<platform name="ios">    
  <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
 </platform>
```

Then convert your file:// link by using the undocumented method

```
window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(filePath)
```

This method performs the conversion into a virtual localhost link that makes the file accessible and bypasses the WkWebView restrictions. A little bit longer sample goes like this

```
let localFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'logo.png';
let convertedPath = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(localFile);
document.getElementById("myImg").src = convertedPath;
```

Comment: This piece of code is valid only for cordova-ios@6+.

Comment: Where should I write `window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(filePath)
` ? in which file?

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I just fixed file protocol 'file://' and web links with target='_blank' 2 days back in my application. WKWebView has issue. But there are some plugins, which can solve this problem.

Try installing [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr](https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr) and [cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix](https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix) plugins, which resolves the issue with file protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I dont get the information with xhrequest but I try to set the scr property to a local file for a script element. This does not seem to work but I found a different solution. I read the .js file from the filesystem and then add the content to the text property of the scriptblock and append it to the body.

Comment: I recently dealt with this issue with file:// URIs and WKWebView rejecting due to CORS and the origin being null. Long term should refactor to use a scheme URI but a quick fix was running (see: https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix)

cordova plugin add @ahovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix